# Displaying a script's stdin within Java

Tags: java, bash, process, inputstream, bufferedreader

At the moment, I have a java program which executes the script `input.sh` as an external process. The script simply echos the line that the user has entered, with an added history functionality.

Here is the code for `input.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=""
while read -e line
do
    echo $line
    history -s $line
done
```

And here is my java code program `Main.java`:

```
public class Main {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
            Process script = pb.command("/bin/sh", "-i","input.sh").start();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(script.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            System.out.println("Starting");

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I execute `./input.sh` in the terminal, the script behaves exactly as it should. It will display what the user has entered, move the cursor when the left and right arrow keys are pressed (instead of showing **^[[D**), pressing up and down will navigate through previously entered commands, and pressing enter will print what the user has just typed. However, when I execute the java program, I cannot see what I am typing, but will display the results just fine.

Can somebody tell me why now characters are showing when inputting into the java program?
Thanks

Comment: is `-e` legal in read?

Comment: `read -e` is legal, it prevents the cursor keys from being read as a character, otherwise `^[[D` will be displayed if the arrow keys are pressed